# Chromed driver not launching when running the script through gitlab pipeline - python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, selenium-chromedriver

I have done one automation using Python and Selenium, and that automation needs to be run through the GitLab CI/CD pipeline, GitLab configured to server machine through GitLab Runner, problem is when am running the script through pipeline getting below error, but when am running the script directly on server its working fine.i have tried all the way but still facing an issue.

```
    def proxy():
    http_proxy = "http://a0ase:pwd@cos.intra:3001"
    https_proxy = "http://a0ase:pwd@cos.intra:3001"
    os.environ['http_proxy'] = http_proxy
    os.environ['https_proxy'] = https_proxy
    env_enable = os.getenv("https_proxy")
    env1_enable = os.getenv("http_proxy")
    print(env_enable)
    print(env1_enable)
    time.sleep(5)


def pre_req():
    global driver,wait,finalPath,obj,s
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1080")
    options.add_argument("user-agent= Chrome/111.0.5563.64")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": finalPath}
    options.add_argument("--lang=en")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(300)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300, poll_frequency=0.1)
    driver.maximize_window()
    print("-----------------------")
                
def Launch_url_and_switch_to_opportunity360():
    print("--------------------------------")
    print("INFO : Launching URL")
    global status, driver, wait, url
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(45)
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as error:
        # handle the exception
        print("An exception occurred:", error)
```

Error:

```
INFO : Launching URL
An exception occurred: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tools\GitLab-Runner\builds\nop\nop-extraction\export.py", line 436, in <module>
    Log_in_saml()
  File "D:\Tools\GitLab-Runner\builds\nop\nop-extraction\export_member.py", line 215, in Log_in_saml
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'uwa-panel panel-form login-panel')]")))
  File "C:\Users\admDXI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x015B8893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x0154B8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x01455058]
```